# Checked Tab does not display associated Content (CSS & HTML)

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am not able to configure the below tab layout in a way that upon checking each tab, related content is being displayed. I've been trying different methods, but none has worked so far. Any ideas what I am missing here? [CodePen space](https://codepen.io/adamsolo/pen/NWJwaXL)

```
body {
      font-family: Menlo, sans-serif;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .tabs-container {
      display: flex;
    }

    .tab {
      display: none;
    }

    .tab-label {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #316542;
      border-bottom: 1.8px solid #316542;
      border-top: 1.8px solid #316542;
      border-left: 1.8px solid #316542;
      transition: background-color 0.3s;
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .tab-label:hover {
      background-color: #74a3833d;
    }

    .tab:checked + .tab-label {
      background-color: #316542;
      color: white;
    }

    .content {
      display: none;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
      padding: 20px;
      font: black;
      border-left: 1.8px solid #316542;
      border-right: 1.8px solid #316542;
      border-bottom: 1.8px solid #316542;
    }

.tab:checked + .tab-label + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: .tab:checked + .tab-label + .content does not select what is wanted. Are you allowed to change the HTML structure?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score -1):

The issue with the provided code is that the CSS selector to display the content based on the checked tab is incorrect. Since your .content divs are not immediately following their corresponding .tab-label, you cannot use the adjacent sibling combinator +.

Instead, you will need to use the general sibling combinator ~ and select the appropriate id of the content. Additionally, the CSS should reflect that all .content elements are siblings and follow all the .tab inputs.

```
<div class="tabs-container">
  <!-- Tab Inputs -->
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" class="tab" checked>
  <label for="tab1" class="tab-label">Section One</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2" class="tab">
  <label for="tab2" class="tab-label">Section Two</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3" class="tab">
  <label for="tab3" class="tab-label">Section Three</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab4" class="tab">
  <label for="tab4" class="tab-label">Section Four</label>

  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab5" class="tab">
  <label for="tab5" class="tab-label">Section Five</label>

  <!-- Content Sections -->
  <div class="content" id="content1">
    Content for Section One
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="content2">
    Content for Section Two
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="content3">
    Content for Section Three
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="content4">
    Content for Section Four
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="content5">
    Content for Section Five
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped in making the tabs switching content, but now I see the content in-line with the tabs, instead of below the tab container. Would you know what is missing from this updated view https://codepen.io/adamsolo/pen/NWJwaXL?

Comment: Just letting anyone here know that I've re-written the code and simplified html - details in the CodePen shared. It works like a charm! Cheers!